# CSS selector: how to select non-element sibling node?

Tags: css, css-selectors

According to the specification here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

> Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: E1 + E2, where
>   E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if E1 and E2
>   share the same parent in the document tree and E1 immediately precedes
>   E2, **ignoring non-element nodes** (such as text nodes and comments).

So how can we select the non-element sibling node. For example: in the following html, how can we select the "Non-element text" text?

```
<div><label>Some text here</label> Non-element text</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't. CSS selectors can only select element nodes. This is why the adjacent sibling combinator works as described.

If you need to apply styles, try applying them to the `div` and overriding them in the `label`. This does depend on what styles you're applying, of course, since some of the styles can't be undone or are subject to inheritance.

Comment: Thank you. 

In fact, that html page is external and I cannot modify it. My main purpose is to parse that page. I am using this tool http://apify.heroku.com/resources/new and want to find a proper css selector for that. But if it is not do-able as you said, I will find another way.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, CSS selectors can only select element nodes.

To solve your problem, you can either wrap the text node in an element, and apply styles on this element, or apply the style on the container element, and override it in the label element.